# How do I properly use super method for subclasses in Dart?

Tags: python, class, dart

I've recently learned object oriented python, and have been trying to learn Dart in the past few days. However, I'm having trouble learning how to make subclasses.

This is the result I want to achieve, in python:

```
class Employee:

  def __init__(self, fistName, lastName, pay):
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.pay = pay

class Developer(Employee):

  def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, pay, languages):
    super().__init__(firstName, lastName, pay)
    self.languages = languages

developer = Developer('John', 'Doe', 5000, ['Python', 'Java'])
```

In dart, this is the code I have so far:

```
class Employee {

  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  num pay;

  Employee(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.pay);
}

class Developer extends Employee{

  List<String> languages;

  Developer(?);
}

void main(){ 
  var developer = new Developer('John', 'Doe', 5000, ['Python', 'Java'])
}
```

How do I complete the code so that I get the same result as in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
class Employee {

  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  num pay;

  Employee(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.pay);
}

class Developer extends Employee{

  List<String> languages;

  Developer(String firstName, String lastName, num pay, this.languages): super(firstName, lastName, pay);
}

void main(){ 
  var developer = new Developer('John', 'Doe', 5000, ['Python', 'Java']);
}
```